# Any justification for an IT policy that query parameters should not be used?

Tags: query-string, corporate-policy

My company, which builds ad server, affiliate network, contact form and CRM software was acquired last year, and we are now in the process of reworking our technology to fit the IT policies and guidelines of the parent corporation.

One of these policies is a tremendous sticking point and causing all sorts of problems for us:

> No query parameters are to be used in any URL visible to the end user

This includes content URLs, ad clickthrough targets, redirects, anything which will either show up in the address bar or in a mouseover status bar update. The effect would be no affiliate ID parameters, media source tracking IDs, session IDs, CMS content selection parameters, anything. Several fundamental functions of our software simply can't be accomplished without passing parameter data from one page to another. In our case, many of these links are from different sites or subdomains, it's not possible to pass data via cookies, either

The only justification I've been given is that query parameters prevent some proxy caches from working properly. This makes no sense to me--I've never heard of such a thing--and nobody is willing or interested in discussing it at length. I've not even been given an example of what specifically is broken or why the policy was created.

In any case, this being a global corporate IT policy, in the end the reasoning doesn't matter, only compliance. Although getting it changed is most likely out of the question, I would still like to understand what valid concerns may have prompted its institution. Understanding the mindset may be a first step towards finding a workaround.

My first thought for a workaround was to embed parameters within the path portion of the URL and extract them with an Apache mod_rewrite, but this is out of the question because:

> Corollary: Every URL must present unique content available through no other URL

So making multiple URLs which actually refer to the same page but contain other parameter data in the URL is also unacceptable.

Questions:

- Is there valid justification for not using query parameters?
- Specifically what proxies or systems fail to work when query parameters are present?
- Does it possibly have something to do with SEO? The corollary makes it appear so.
- What workarounds might there be for passing data from one site to another under this restriction?

Comment: Even if thee werent any good reasons to do it, its what your employer wants. I dont think a rational argument is going to change that, not given what you have already stated.

Comment: My first thought is... generate *something* unique for every parametrized request, even if it's something pointless like a hash of the parameters. But yeah, this seems asinine... I wonder if someone didn't read about vulnerabilities involving sensitive information in querystrings, and come away with the wrong idea as to what the solution should be.

Comment: @GrayWizardx Yes, you're right about that! I added a clarification that I don't expect to get it changed, but would like to understand what prompted them to create such a policy so that I can know what types of concerns are uppermost in their minds.

Comment: @Shog9: easiest approach: render out the requested URI in each of those cases and you suddenly have unique content at each URI

Comment: @ryandenki: how did you resolve this?  do they still insist on their silly policies?

Comment: @justsomebody It was resolved by the CTO unilaterally changing the policy and overriding the IT director after the IT director was unable to come up with a justification for the policy.

Answer (score 2):

i only have answer for the "workaround" question: use PATH_INFO.

**edit** to be more specific

instead of `/banner.php?what=ever&any=thing` use `/banner.php/what=ever/any=thing`.  apache will still serve the request through `/banner.php`, and `/what=ever/any=thing` will be present in `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.  you'll have to `rawurldecode` and `explode` the string yourself since the webserver won't do that for you, but that's no big deal.

Comment: That's basically what I was thinking with the mod_rewrite, but since that would create multiple URLs for the same content, if falls afoul of the "unique URLs only" corollary and is also prohibited. :-(

Comment: aha.  i didn't pay close enough attention and thought this was about ads only.  looks like this leaves the OP in a dead end street.  that's actually a good thing for him, since the suits are rarely interested in killing their own business, and the situation will eventually resolve.